# Make flex rows act as columns to preserve time-line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First of all: thank you for your time!
I'm looking to make a blog with Flex boxing. I've been looking at several places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox), [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [here](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/responsive-multi-column-lists-flexbox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079521/flex-items-create-space-between-them-when-they-wrap), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553835/flex-wrap-with-rows-of-different-heights) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899466/positioning-flex-items-on-top-of-each-other-in-grid-without-wrapping-them)) but I can't get the "blog" effect I want. I'm looking to make a two column layout that could be made with `flex-direction: column;`.
Unfortunately this would result in a column of the most recent posts with a column of much older posts on its side. If I wan't to keep the time-line of the blog relevant I feel like I'll need to use `flex-direction: row;` in combination with `flex-wrap: wrap;`.
This option works well with same-height posts but results in lost space when the heights varies.

On the left-side is my current result, on the right-side the desired one:
[image: Current screenshot]

I realize that this is clearly a grid that requires two columns rather than rows. But is there a way to make the `align-items` and `align-content` properties achieve this kind of layout on a row-based Flex box *(and this without Javascript)*? Or, if it is impossible like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553835/flex-wrap-with-rows-of-different-heights) would suggest,is there a work-around to use columns but keep the time-line relevant? Should I use something else than Flex?
[image: Desired grid]

This is my current situation made as simple as possible:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.container div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div>
    4
  </div>
  <div>
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Maxime

Comment: No, that will not work, you'll need script or use float, or CSS grid ... and there is Masonry as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are aiming for is called a **[Masonry effect](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/)**.

It can be done using **[CSS3 columns](https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.4vyexfufh)** , **[Flex-box](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/eAqzk)** , or by applying a **[custom plugin.](https://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/)**

There is however some issues using CSS columns, since they are a relatively new spec and they might cause some unwanted behavior for your visitors.

You can see what I am referring to at the **[Can I use chart for CSS3 columns](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)**.

My advice is to head for the Flexbox variant, which will be the less-problematic approach using **[the right prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)**.

Look up the **[codepen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/eAqzk)** I've posted about.

Simply change the width of the columns and use it out-of-the-box

```
div#masonry img {  // and the img here will be your post
  width: 33.3%; // to > 49.5% or whatever suits your needs
  transition: .8s opacity;
}
```

Or you can dig in the website of the most used **[JS Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**, and all you need to do is wrap your head around the works of it.